# Bootstrap AngularJS modal redirecting the user properly, but the page looks blacked out

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, redirect, model-view-controller

I have a modal window aith an "OK" button that closes it and redirects the user to the main page.

When I'm clicking on it it is redirecting the user to the main page successfully, but the page looks kind of blacked out.

I tried to use data-backdrop="false" in the button, but still I got the same result.

The redirection I'm using:

ng-click="go('/')" in the button

And controller:

```
$scope.go = function ( path ) {
    $location.path( path );
```

P.S: If I reload that page, it will looks properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem by removing the modal-backdrop in your button event. Make sure you are selecting your modal container correctly when using this.

```
$('#your-modal-id').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```